# Use python to extract lines that contain different keywords into dictionaries

Tags: python, parsing

So have an input file to script like as follows:

```
20248109|Generic|1|xxx|2|yyy|LINEA|68.66|68.67|True|2920958141272
.
.
.
21248109|Generic|3|xxx|4|www|LINEB|7618|7622|True|2920958281071.97
```

want the python script to iterate through and put LINEA into dictionary like as follows `{{1:[68.66,68.67]},{3:[7618,7622]}}`

here's as far as i've gotten:

```
Key = ["LINEA", "LINEB"]
fin = open(path)
test = []
for line in fin.readlines():
    if True in [item in line for item in Key]:
       test.append(line)
```

Any help at all would be fantastic.

Comment: -1 because you have no idea about the different between True and 'True'

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use the `csv` module:

```
import csv
with open(path, "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="|")
```

Then, you can iterate over the lines:

```
test = []
for row in reader:
    if row[6] in Key:
        test.append({int(row[2]): row[7:9]})
```

Comment: when i try this, the row is out of range (row[6])

Comment: On your test data, the rows contain 11 columns, `row[6]` would contain `LINEA`, for example. If your actual data does not look like the example you gave, you need to edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
keys = ["LINEA", "LINEB"]
with open(path) as fin
    answer = {line.partition("Generic|")[-1]:line for line in fin if any(key in line for key in keys)}
```

To edit your answer directly, you're actually quite close:

```
Key = ["LINEA", "LINEB"]
fin = open(path)
test = {} # dictionary
for line in fin.readlines():
    if True in [item in line for item in Key]:
       dict_key = line.partition("Generic|")[-1]
       test[dict_key] = line
```

Comment: would be preferrable to use the `with` construct with `fin` here.